# JavaScript Closure: Returning a Function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am working my way through a JavaScript lecture series by Douglas Crockford. I am confused by a code example he is showing to illustrate 'closure':

```js
var digit_name = (function () {
  var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
  
  return function (n) {
    return names[n];
  };
  
}());

alert(digit_name(3));
```

How/why can `digit_name` take an argument when no parameter is specified in the definition (the outermost function)? How does the argument (in this case `3`) know to correspond to `n` within the inner function definition during invocation?

Comment: When it's defined it's an IIFE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `digit_name` stores the inner function `return`ed by the outer function, which is an **Immediately Executed Function Expression**, where the inner function has the signature with one parameter and that's what is stored in the `digit_name`.

```
function (n) {
  return names[n];
}
```

Ultimately, the above will be the `digit_name` and the `names` is a private variable, which is bundled with the environment of `digit_name`. The concept of private variable is possible only using closures.

To make it clear, see this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Theres a self calling, anonymous function (function(){})() . So digit_name is not the function, its what the function outputs in is return statement.So this happens inside the browser:

```
var digit_name=(function(){})();
var digit_name=function(n){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer function is an IIFE, an immediately-invoked function expression. That function is ran when the script starts and therefore the inner function returned by the IIFE is what is assigned to digit_name.

The "magic" of the closure if that this inner function still has access to everything in the closure (such as the names array).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: ...and the inner function returns a function that takes a parameter.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that the inner function is the one that is returned.